# How do I only copy a file, then manually navigate to another destination, and then paste it. (Without a fixed path)

Tags: windows, command-line, unix, batch

**I need to move a file from one directory to another without any fixed paths in the copy/paste command. That means I likely cannot have a one-liner copy/paste command:**

**The folder structure is as follows:**

> - Mainfolder
>
>   - Files.dir
>   - log.dir
>   - executable.bat

**This is my code:**

```
cd log
if exist flist.log del flist.log
cd ..
cd Files
dir /b /a-d>flist.log
copy flist.log
cd ..
cd log
paste flist.log
```

Or, if possible have something like this:

```
cd log
if exist flist.log del flist.log
cd ..
cd Files
dir /b /a-d>flist.log (save in Files.dir without a fixed path)
```

I cannot use a fixed path, because the folder this is executed in, needs to be able to move.

**Thanks :)**

Comment: `Files.dir`? Are you trying to write a single batch script for Windows, Unix, _and_ OpenVMS?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**You don't.** Copy/paste of files generally does not exist in the command shell.

Instead you directly tell it where to move the file:

```
if exist log\flist.log del log\flist.log

cd Files
dir /b /a-d > flist.log

move flist.log ..\log\
```

Or, in fact, directly tell it where to *write* the file in the first place:

```
cd Files
dir /b /a-d > ..\log\flist.log
```

There is no basis for your "No oneliners" requirement. As you can see, none of the examples above use a fixed path; **all commands accept relative paths** (with `..` or without) the same way as `cd` does.

Comment: **This worked, Thank you!** I looked for an answer to this, but i only found how to use xcopy and things like that. Mostly oneliners with fixed paths. It seemed like a simple thing to solve, but it was not easy finding an answer like yours :)

Answer (score 0):

It appears the intent of your script is to construct a list of files that are contained in the subdirectory `files` of your current working directory, the list being placed in subdirectory `log` which is alongside `files`.

Relative paths work, no need to be `cd`-ing all over the place.

`dir /b /a-d  files  >log\flist.log`

It it's intentional that you end up with two copies of the listing, which seems to be the case in your first example, then follow that up with

`copy /y  log\flist.log  files\flist.log`